# Selecting value from array results

Tags: php, arrays

Being new to learning PHP I am having trouble with understanding how to select/echo/extract a value from array result a API script returns.

Using the standard:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($ups_rates->rates);
echo "</pre>";
```

The results returned look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [code] => 03
            [cost] => 19.58
            [desc] => UPS Ground
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [code] => 12
            [cost] => 41.69
            [desc] => UPS 3 Day Select
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [code] => 02
            [cost] => 59.90
            [desc] => UPS 2nd Day Air
        )
)
```

If I am only needing to work with the values of the first array result: Code 3, 19.58, UPS Ground ---   what is the correct way to echo one or more of those values?

**I thought:**

```
$test = $ups_rates[0][cost];
echo $test;
```

This is obviously wrong and my lack of understanding the array results isn't improving, can someone please show me how I would echo an individual value of the returned array and/or assign it to a variable to echo the normal way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo $ups_rates->rates[0]["cost"];
```

See [Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

More:

*To iterate over the array*

```
foreach ($ups_rates->rates as $rate) {
    echo $rate["cost"];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank You! I am trying to read the info on arrays, just not getting it quite yet. Thanks for the help, will accept answer in a few minutes when it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = $ups_rates->rates;
$cost = $array[0]['cost'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $ups_rates->rates[0]['code'];
echo $ups_rates->rates[0]['cost'];
echo $ups_rates->rates[0]['desc'];
```

should print out all 3

`rates[0]` is the first element of your array and you can index into that array by appending a `['key']` index onto the end

the only thing you forgot is `'` marks